# Как вывести день недели с помощью getDayOfWeek на русском языке?

Tags: java

Как вывести день недели с помощью getDayOfWeek на русском языке?

```
int i = 0;

while (today.isAfter(birthday)){
    birthday = birthday.plusYears(1);
    System.out.println(i + " - " + birthday + " " + birthday.getDayOfWeek());
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону enum [DayOfWeek](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html)

```
public String getDisplayName(TextStyle style,
                         Locale locale)
```

Который принимае параметры locale и style

Другой пример [отсюда](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/GetDaysOfTheWeekfordifferentlocale.htm)

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DaysOfTheWeek {
  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    Locale usersLocale = Locale.getDefault();

    DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols(usersLocale);
    String weekdays[] = dfs.getWeekdays();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(usersLocale);

    int firstDayOfWeek = cal.getFirstDayOfWeek();
    int dayOfWeek;

    for (dayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek; dayOfWeek < weekdays.length; dayOfWeek++)
      System.out.println(weekdays[dayOfWeek]);

    for (dayOfWeek = 0; dayOfWeek < firstDayOfWeek; dayOfWeek++)
      System.out.println(weekdays[dayOfWeek]);
  }
}
```